# Error InflateException: Binary XML file line #20

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I'm get this error when I'm trying make a custom ListView from data into sqlite.
I'm trying to get data from sqlite and inflate this data on custom layout using baseadapter.

Error:

```
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-17 13:18:37.078: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at br.com.ricainformatica.rcforcavendas.adapters.AdapterListClientes.getView(AdapterListClientes.java:49)
```

Comment: Show us your xml file

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040385/android-view-inflateexception helps you

Comment: I try add my xml but I can't. Stackoverflow says that my message have more code.

Comment: My xml http://pastebin.com/2EcpQjcn

Comment: And my Activity http://pastebin.com/tyV2vf5f

Comment: Are you sure you have the library in your project?

Comment: There should be more of the stack trace after what you have here, such as a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Thanks Albus Shin, my error was add this in xml. <android.support.v7.widget.Space
           android:id="@+id/space2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />